# processing mysql assoc results through various classes

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I've recently started yet another project and my boss is insisting that we use the MVC model, the problem being that due to many articles showing different ways to do this we havent managed to agree on what a proper MVC model should look like.

So here's my problem for this project (whether this is the correct way to do it or not) I am using the following baseline rules

Controller classes manage both getting the data from the model classes and passing the data to the view classes and retrieving the view and displaying it

Model classes managhe all database actions and return the data using `mysql_fetch_assoc`

View classes create the views using the data etc.

So my issue is with processing the information from `mysql_fetch_assoc` normally you would do something like this (assuming we have already run a query)

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["username"];
}
```

but as I'm processing the results in the view class rather than the model how do I cycle through all of the results when I have already passed the assoc array to the view, currently I'm getting a problem where it keeps looping through the results until it hits a memory size error so for some reason it isn't able to figure out how many results it needs to cycle through

My current code snippets are below sorry for the bad explainations.

Controller
    require_once 'admin_model.php';
    require_once 'admin_view.php';

```
class admin_controller {
    public $model;
    public $view;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->model = new admin_model;
        $this->view = new admin_view;
    }

    public function get_group_view() {
        $in_model = $this->model->get_group_view();
        $in_view = $this->view->get_group_view ($in_model);

        echo $in_view;
    }
```

Model
    class admin_model {

```
    public function get_group_view() {
        $query = mysql_query("
            SELECT
                group_id,
                group_name
            FROM
                user_groups
        ");

        return mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    }
}
```

View

```
class admin_view {

    public function get_group_view($group_data) {

        while($group_data) {
            $output .= $group_data['group_id'] . '###' . $group_data['group_name'] . '<hr />';
        }

        return $output;
    }

}
```

Which currently returns the error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 133693393 bytes)
```

So can someone please advise me on the best way to go through the results without moving 'mysql_fetch_assoc' function from the model class?

PS I know I'm probably doing MVC completely wrong but it works for us and we don't want to have to research and change our code yet again thanks.

Comment: K, first suggestion if your starting building this thing, use mysqli or PDO, not mysql_*, deprecation and stuff, you'll hear a lot of it ;)

Comment: I'm not sure but looks like you have the loop that will never finished as get_group_view() every time will return first row of the query

Comment: @RomanS true, mysql_fetch_assoc only returns a result in the result set, so while is always true (unless no results were returned,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not return the MySQL Result - you should do:

```
 $return = array();
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT group_id, group_name FROM user_groups");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     $return[] = $row;
 }
 mysql_free_result($row);
 return $return;
```

And you should fix the $group_data bug per @Roman_S . The correct use, along with the above code is

```
public function get_group_view($group_data) {
    $output = '';
    foreach($group_data as $group) {
        $output .= $group['group_id'] . '###' . $group['group_name'] . '<hr />';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Finally you should migrate to MySQLi or PDO if possible.

Comment: I'd like to echo your sentiments about PDO, PDO can provide a lot more flexibility in situations like this.

Comment: You mean the word PDO he wrote second after MySQLi? :)

Comment: Thank you that works perfect although there is a slight typo in the first code snippet `$result` should of been `$row` and as for switching over to mySQLi or PDO, I have looked in to this before and so far I'm really liking PDO but as I said my boss really wants us to get into some sort of model such as my crude attempt at MVC so at the moment I'm kind of in a rapid prototyping phase so it's basically get it working as fast as possible with what I know but eventually it will be changed to PDO sooner rather than later, thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks - I've fixed it for future people referencing the question.

Regarding MySQLi vs. PDO. I use MySQLi because I started with mysql before either existed then switched to MySQLi when it came out. I may move to PDO for the next project I guess but only if I need DBAL will it be worth learning a new framework.

Answer (score 2):

You have en error here

```
    while($group_data) {
        $output .= $group_data['group_id'] . '###' . $group_data['group_name'] . '<hr />';
    }
```

If `$group_data` is not empty - your loop will never end.

Comment: I knew this that was my main issue I should of made that clearer I was looking for a way to process the mysql assoc without running in to this issue but thanks for your help I've upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

To give a suggestion on how to handle database control.

When using PDO for instance

```
$pdoInst = new PDO( .. );
```

and we have a method somewhere that validates every statement the $pdoInst produces

```
abstract class .. {
  public static function validateStmt($stmt) {
    if($stmt !== false) { .. }
      // everything else you like, even error handling, log files, etc.
    }
  }
}
```

a prepared statement like the `get_group_view` method will look like the following

```
public function get_group_view { 
  $stmt = $pdoInst->prepare(" .. QUERY .. ");
  // the return can be wrapped in a method to handle errors, etc, which can be done
  // here or else where.
  $stmt->execute() // returns true or false
  return $stmt;
}
```

now for iteration

```
public function get_group_view($group_data) {
  $output = "";
  // validate the statement, can be done here or else where as said before
  if($pdoInst::validateStmt($group_data)) {
    // many ways how to iterate, foreach is just one.
    foreach($group_data as $index => $group) {
      $output .= $group['group_id'] . '###' . $group['group_name'] . '<hr />';
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

The nicest thing about PDO is that you can extend the classes with custom ones. You can add functionality that adds more value to your Model.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have looked in to PDO and so far I really like it, I will be using this and your advice. thanks again :)